# Number of roots of the following function defined using the definite integral

Tags: derivatives

I have the following function:

$F(x)= \int_{0}^{x} \exp(t)(t^2-3t-5)dt$

The problem is to find the number of roots of $F(x)=0$ in the interval $(0,4)$. I calculated it's derivative using the Leibniz rule as follows:

$F'(x)=\exp(x)(x^2-3x-5)$

I suppose that this function$(F('(x))$ will not have any roots between $(0,4)$. Can I say this for the function $F(x)$ also. If I can, how can I prove it formally. I am confused and not able to proceed from here. Please take some time to look at it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what denotes $tl$?

Comment: I have corrected it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can calculate the integral in elementary way then just put it in form of $exp(x)P(x)$. Exponential function is never zero so you have to find the roots of $P(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You know that $F'(x)$ does not have any roots between $0$ and $4$, so it's always increasing or decreasing in this interval. In your case, it's decreasing. You also know that $F(0)=0$. Therefore in this interval $F(x)<0$. In a more general problem, if $F'$ does not have a root in a given interval $(a,b)$, you would need to look at the values of $F$ at the two ends of the interval. If $F(a)$ and $F(b)$ have the same sign, then there is no root. If they have opposite sign you have one root.

Comment: So, it means this $F(x)$ will have no roots between $(0,4)$. Am I right because at zero, the function is zero and it is decreasing in nature. The function will never cross x axis in the interval $(0,4)$.

Comment: Correct. Just remember to always check the ends of the interval. For example, if $F(x)=-x^3+27$ and you look in the interval $(1,4)$, $F'(x)=-3x^2<0$, like in this problem. But $F(1)>0$ and $F(4)<0$, so there is a root somewhere in that interval, $(3)$.